# Hiding all elements that doesn't have a particular class nested deep in them

Tags: javascript

[In this very webpage](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/topic:javascript), have about 70 elements, all with the class "card".

Some of the about 70 elements holds another element with the class "pro-content", which is **nested** deep inside them.

[In this image you could see 2 elements. One with the "pro-content" class and an one without, from left to right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smj0q.png)

---

My aim is to hide all elements with this "pro-content" class and keep all others that doesn't have it.

Given the elements with "pro-content" are childNodes, I tried to use the following for...of loop:

```
let cardoo = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

for ( const element of cardoo ) {
    if ( !$(element).hasClass('pro-content') ) {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Yet, this code doesn't work properly - It deletes all elements, instead just these without the "pro-content" class.

Note: I would have proffered a pure vanilla ES16 solution, especially to practice more of the ES16-DOMapi relations but if there is no other option, I would use a pure jQuery/ES16-jQuery solution.

Comment: please make a snippet ( the `<>` ) so that we can try

Comment: `!$(element).hasClass('pro-content')`

Comment: One can try anything live on the webpage. I putted the link instead making a snippet (if you meant to codepen snippet).

Comment: Haim, sorry, copied an old example. I already tried that. Doesn't work. It deletes all elements instead just these **without** the pro-content element.

Comment: Haim, question edited.

Comment: OK... I think a bunch of us have made the mistake in thinking that the element with `card` may also have `pro-content`... perhaps worth a small rewrite to make that very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***With jQuery***

You don't need an explicit loop if you use jQuery's `:has()` selector.

```
$(".card:has('.pro-content')").hide();
```

This will select all `.card` elements have have a *descendant* with the `pro-content` class.

---

***Without jQuery***

To do this without a library dependency, use querySelector/All.

```
for (const card of document.querySelectorAll(".card")) {
  if (!card.querySelector(".pro-content")) {
    card.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

---

Or you can use the native `.closest()` method like this if you prefer:

```
for (const pro of document.querySelectorAll(".pro-content")) {
  const card = pro.closest(".card");
  if (card) {
    card.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Though you'll need to patch `.closest()` into some browsers that don't have it yet.

Comment: Hi! You understood me correctly! It worked! Thank you!

Comment: I don´t test the second variant - but this querySelector don´t work on the sourcecode because the classes or not assigned to the same element.

Comment: @FrankWisniewski: The non-jQuery will work, but I accidentally put a `!` in the condition. Now it's fixed. The use of `querySelector` is correct because it will look for a `pro-content` element *nested inside* the current `card` and then hide the current `card` if found.

Comment: OK, but `closest` is jQuery? 
.

Comment: This works but a negative sign (!) should be added (it's all **without** the "pro-content" class.

Comment: @zippydippy are you there? :) Please see one comment above.

Comment: You just need to add this ! there.

Comment: @J.Doe: Yeah, lost sight of that. The `!` was correct. I'll put it back.

Comment: @FrankWisniewski: Some browsers now include it, but others will need a patch.

Answer (score 1):

After a look in the source Code i think this oneliner makes the job:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.pro-content').forEach(el => el.parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none');
```

Comment: Some browsers add `.forEach` to an HTMLCollection and others do not. You'll need to add a patch for this to be cross browser safe. It also makes the assumption that there are no `pro-content` on the page that are not nested exactly two levels within a `.card`. Some verification should be done.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
$('.card').each((i, el) => {
    if ($(el).find('.pro-content').length) {
        $(el).hide();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should resolve your problem. valid cards (ie having pro content) are turned red in this example, and invalid are turned blue. You can adjust the hit and not-hit classes to your wishes (ie "display:none" or "display:block". Hopefully this solves your issue.

If you have any problems please ask in the comments.

```js
(function($) {
  let cardoo = $('.card')

  cardoo.each(function() {
   if($(this).find('.pro-content').length !== 0) {
    $(this).addClass("hit");
     } else {
     $(this).addClass("not-hit");
     }
  });
 
})( jQuery );
```

```css
.card {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

.hit {
  background:red;
}

.not-hit {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="other_content">x</div></div></div>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="other_content">x</div></div></div>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="other_content">x</div></div></div>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="pro-content">PRO</div></div></div>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="other_content">x</div></div></div>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="other_content">x</div></div></div>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="other_content">x</div></div></div>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="pro-content">PRO</div></div></div>
<div>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="pro-content">PRO</div></div></div>
<div class="card"><div class="depeer-we-go"><div class="other_content">x</div></div></div>
```